# Daily stock outstanding and context transition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm creating a stock analysis dashboard.

I have a [PRODUCT] Dimension

`| Product ID | StockEntryDate | StockExitDate  |`

I also have a [DATE] dimension.

What I've succesfully done is to create a measure in order to visualize the stock for any given date.

```
Stock = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            PRODUCT,
            (
                MIN ( CALENDAR[Date] ) > PRODUCT[StockEntryDate] && 
                NOT ISBLANK(PRODUCT[StockEntryDate])
            ) && 
            (
                MAX ( CALENDAR[Date] ) < PRODUCT[StockExitDate] ||
                ISBLANK ( PRODUCT[StockExitDate] )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I put this in a barchart and for each given date I have the stock outstanding. I can also drop in something like PRODUCT[Category] and for each given day I have a rundown of the stock by category.

[image: Bar chart]

Now, if I select a category in a month. Like May 2019 in my histogram. No problem I can either select it or highlight it. **However that context does not transit outside of the visual.**

[image: The date context doesn't transit to the Product Dimension]

I'm missing something regarding context transition but I can't find what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick sample. Is this it?

[image]

```
Active ID = 
VAR _s = MIN('Date'[Date])
VAR _e = MAX('Date'[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Table2;
            [Start] <= _e &&
            [End] >= _s
        )
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. Can you elaborate why using a measure with variables is the way to go?